# Two Table Join with Sub-query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

So I am working on an exercise to improve my SQL skills and I need to modify my query to add a subquery that looks for the existence of a customer ID in the CUSTOMERS table.  The exercise also notes that this is a correlated sub-query so you will have to match the customer ID from the sub-query to the customer ID in the outer query.  The title of the section of this exercise is "Two Table Join with Subquery".  After researching and trying for a few hours now, I've exhausted all my resources but one.  Any help would be much appreciated! (I am using Oracle Apex for this.)

```
SELECT ORDER_ID, ORDER_MODE, CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID
FROM ORDERS
NATURAL JOIN ORDER_ITEMS;
```

[image: Customers Table]

[image: ORDER_ITEMS Table]

[image: ORDERS Table]

[image: PRODUCT_DESCRIPTIONS Table]

Comment: A sample set of data would be helpful

Comment: I've added the table data!

Comment: check the solution and let be know whether it helped :)

Comment: That worked great!  Just one last thing I hope you could help me with!  The exercise now wants me to modify the previous SQL query to add the translated name column from the PRODUCT_DESCRIPTIONS table. I've added that table data to the post, thanks!

Comment: Since you are learning I would like to help you rather giving the answer, so now you have product_id in one of the tables join that id to products and in the select statement select the translation name

Comment: let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: I tried adding TRANSLATED_NAME.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTIONS to the first select line but that didn't work.

Comment: product description is the table name so it should come like PRODUCT_DESCRIPTIONS.TRANSLATED_NAME

Comment: I modified the answer so that you can check, also try to use alias for table that is easier to code and increases readability as well :)

Comment: By the way, since you are just starting out with SQL, there is no requirement to code in caps-lock. Lowercase is used to improve readability in every other language so so why not SQL too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using exists you can check for existence,

```
SELECT O.ORDER_ID, O.ORDER_MODE, O.CUSTOMER_ID, OI.PRODUCT_ID
FROM ORDERS O
INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS OI on O.ORDER_ID=OI.ORDER_ID
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS C
WHERE O.CUSTOMER_ID=C.CUSTOMER_ID
);
```

This would do the second,

```
SELECT O.ORDER_ID, O.ORDER_MODE, O.CUSTOMER_ID, OI.PRODUCT_ID,P.TRANSLATED_NAME
FROM ORDERS O
INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS OI on O.ORDER_ID=OI.ORDER_ID
INNER JOIN PRODUCT_DESCRIPTIONS P on P.PRODUCT_ID=OI.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS C
WHERE O.CUSTOMER_ID=C.CUSTOMER_ID
);
```